# NodeJS Encoding Issue for Vowels

Tags: node.js, windows, typescript, encoding

I am facing encoding issues when I am encoding Vowels/Umlaute like ä,ü,ö.
These are interpreted as ? signs.

For example:

```
console.log("ä");
```

shows as ? in the console.

But if I echo directly in the console

```
echo "ä"
```

it is shown as "ä".

I am yet not sure if the issue is in the Windows configuration or in the NodeJS app.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it.
Unfortunately the standard windows encoding was set to ANSI.

I switched it to UTF8 using Notepad++ - now it works!

https://superuser.com/questions/290593/how-to-convert-character-encodings-on-windows